# Concatenated Alexa Certify Code

Tags: javascript, concatenation, gruntjs, minify, alexa-internet

I currently have a lofty goal of getting all ( or at least most ) of our javascript and css concatenated and minified into an external file for our site.

Alexa tracking is giving me a bit of a headache.
The Alexa coverage report shows that it can't find the tracking script on the pages where it has been made external.

I see the code in the external script, I know that it is firing, and there are no JavaScript errors on the page.

How does Alexa certify that these pages have the script? Do they crawl the page and wait for a callback from the script? or do they literally scan the source of the page for the script?

Does anybody know, or have a solution to this other than just making the JS inline again?

Alexa Code:

```
_atrk_opts = { atrk_acct:"###", domain:"###",dynamic: true};
(function() { var as = document.createElement('script'); as.type = 'text/javascript'; as.async = true; as.src = "https://d31qbv1cthcecs.cloudfront.net/atrk.js"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(as, s); })();
```

Comment: It could potentially be a scoping issue, a function being defined in the wrong scope etc. Are you able to post this alexa tracking script that you've made external?

Comment: There's one variable and an anonymous function. Both stay in the global scope
I'll update the question with the Alexa code (without our account ids)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: This was a long time ago, but I remember that we moved most of our 3rd party tracking and marketing scripts into google tag manager (http://www.google.com/tagmanager/) We may have used this for Alexa as well. I don't remember for sure. I remember it being really frustrating that Alexa wouldn't pick it up. Good luck!